# C++, WCHAR[] to std::cout and comparision

Tags: c++, winapi, wchar-t, widechar

I need to put WCHAR[] to std::cout ... It is a part of PWLAN_CONNECTION_NOTIFICATION_DATA passed from Native Wifi API callback.

I tried simply std::cout << var; but it prints out the numeric address of first char. the comparision (`var == L"some text"`) doesn't work either. The debugger returns the expected value, however the comparision returns 0. How can I convert this array to a standard string(std::string)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: THe comparison `"some text"=="some text"` can already fail, with plain `char*`. Reason: you can compare strings in C with `==`. Use C++; `std::wstring(L"text")==std::wstring(L"text")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming var is a `wchar_t *`, `var == L"some text"` does a pointer comparison. In order to compare the string pointed to by var, use a function such as `wcscmp`.

Answer (score 12):

Some solutions:

- Write to std::wcout instead
- Convert:

  - The standard way, using std::codecvt
  - The Win32 way, using WideCharToMultibyte

Answer (score 10):

For printing to `cout`, you should use `std::wcout` instead.

As for the comparison, I'm not really sure what you mean.

- if `var` is a `wchar_t[]`, then you are comparing two pointers. And the result will most likely be false, because while the string contents may be the same, they are physically allocated in different memory locations. The answer is to either use a function like `strcmp` which compares C-style strings (char pointers), or to use the C++ string class.
- and the `operator==` usually returns a `bool`, not an integer. So it can return `false`, but it can't return `0`... Unless you've created some weird overload yourself. (and that is only possible if `var` is a user-defined type.

Comment: I assume you meant `wcscmp`? C++ really should have overloaded `strcmp()` to take anything stringlike. But unfortunately only the math part of the standard C library got that treatment.

Comment: True. I meant "the strcmp family of functions". That's why I said "a function like".

Answer (score 3):

use the following

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define tcout wcout
#else
#define tcout cout
#endif
```