# Outputting 'wchar_t*' to an 'ofstream'

Tags: c++, file, std, wchar-t, wofstream

I want to output a text to a file via two pointers that I have declared:

```
wchar_t   *Col1="dsffsd", *Col2="sdfsf";
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
std::ofstream fout;
fout.open(NativeDatabasePathHist);
fout<<"testing";
fout<<" "<<Col1<<" "<<Col2;
fout.close();
```

And here is what I am getting:

> testing 113 113

Why is it that when I print `Col1` and `Col2`, I am getting numbers instead of strings?

Comment: That shouldn't output anything since those literals aren't wide. Anyway, you probably want `std::owfstream` if you are indeed using wide strings.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493785/how-i-can-print-the-wchar-t-values-to-console

Comment: Thanks chris your comment was helpful but you write `std::owfstream` instead of `std::wofstream` :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First, use `std::wofstream` instead of `std::ofstream`.

Also, use the `L` prefix on your text string to indicate that your text is **wide character** text:

```
wchar_t   *Col1=L"dsffsd"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have written it using wide characters (`wchar_t`), you need to look at the resulting file with something that understands wide characters.

Comment: I have to get `Col1` & `Col2` as `wchar_t`. How I can convert it to char?

Comment: @Aan:  well, since those strings don't have any characters actually requiring a wide representation, you could simply change the type to `char`.  If this is an example using dummy data, but real data will have 16-bit code points, then use a library function like `wctomb()` ("wide character to multi-byte").

Comment: In this case I tried `fout<<" "<<(char*)Col1<<" "<<(char*)Col2;` but this output the first character pointed by Col1 & Col2 ??

Comment: @Aan:  sorry, I meant change the first line to `char *Col1="dsffsd", *Col2="sdfsf";`