# wide character literal string in C++

Tags: c++

Can someone explain to me what is wide character string and how to use them with examples. For example:

```
std::cout<<L"\115";
```

Why do I get 0x100000f90 as output instead of M when I just use

```
std::cout<<"\115";
```

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107608/whats-wrong-with-c-wchar-t-and-wstrings-what-are-some-alternatives-to-wide

Comment: wchar should be sent to wcout.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493785/how-i-can-print-the-wchar-t-values-to-console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the second part of your question if you want to output wide characters then you need to use [`std::wcout`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/wcout/)