# How do you best utilize wcsdup?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, strdup, wcsdup

I'm writing code and a good portion of it requires returning wchar arrays.  Returning wstrings aren't really an option (although I can use them) and I know I can pass a pointer as an argument and populate that, but I'm looking specifically to return a pointer to this array of wide chars.  The first few iterations, I found that I would return the arrays alright, but by the time they are processed and printed, the memory would be overwritten and I would be left with gibberish.  To fix this, I started using wcsdup, which fixed everything, but I'm struggling to grasp exactly what is happening, and thus, when it should be called so that it works and I leak no memory.  As it is, I pretty much use wcsdup every time I return a string and every time a string is returned, which I know leaks memory.  Here is what I'm doing.  Where and why should I use wcsdup, or is there a better solution than wcsdup altogether?

```
wchar_t *intToWChar(int toConvert, int base)
{
    wchar_t converted[12];
    /* Conversion happens... */
    return converted;
}

wchar_t *intToHexWChar(int toConvert)
{
    /* Largest int is 8 hex digits, plus "0x", plus /0 is 11 characters. */
    wchar_t converted[11];

    /* Prefix with "0x" for hex string. */
    converted[0] = L'0';
    converted[1] = L'x';

    /* Populate the rest of converted with the number in hex. */
    wchar_t *hexString = intToWChar(toConvert, 16);
    wcscpy((converted + 2), hexString);

    return converted;
}

int main()
{
    wchar_t *hexConversion = intToHexWChar(12345);
    /* Other code. */

    /* Without wcsdup calls, this spits out gibberish. */
    wcout << "12345 in Hex is " << hexConversion << endl;
}
```

Comment: `intToWChar` and `intToHexWChar` both return a pointer to a variable that will be out of scope after the function is complete. Don't do this.

Comment: Don't you need [wcout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493785/how-i-can-print-the-wchar-t-values-to-console) here?

Comment: And why can't you just return a std::wstring instead of a raw pointer?

Comment: I do need wcout, but that's less important.  The reason I haven't been using wstring is because this needs to fit into others' code.  But now that I look at it I guess it's possible to use them until the last step and then extract a wchar array from the string...

Comment: --and others' code works almost exclusively with wchar arrays for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wchar_t *intToWChar(int toConvert, int base)
{
    wchar_t converted[12];
    /* Conversion happens... */
    return converted;
}
```

This returns a pointer to a local variable.

```
wchar_t *hexString = intToWChar(toConvert, 16);
```

After this line, `hexString` will point to invalid memory and using it is undefined (may still have value or may be garbage!).

You do the same thing with the return from `intToHexWChar`.

Solutions:

- use `std::wstring`
- use `std::vector<wchar_t>`
- pass in an array to the function for it to use
- use smart pointers
- use dynamic memory allocation (please don't!)

Note: you might also need to change to `wcout` instead of `cout`

Comment: Okay, now let me add a level of abstraction.  Often times, these strings/char arrays are being stored in structs to be later retrieved with myStruct.GetString().  I realize I can't really keep a pointer to a char array in a struct and expect the memory to be untouched, but wouldn't a wstring make this a struct of variable size, and if so, isn't that bad?

Comment: The only problem would be if you were writing binary data and expected a fixed size record. I would hazard a guess that most real-world data in modern C++ is not fixed size, but contains `std::string` as well as standard container classes (which also have variable size). As your question stands, I think this is a good answer. But since you don't actually give us the "real" usage, I don't know that we can answer better.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged your question with 'C++' the answer is a resounding: no, you should not use `wcsdup` at all. Instead, for passing arrays of `wchar_t` values around, use `std::vector<wchar_t>`.

If needed, you can turn those into a `wchar_t*` by taking the address of the first element (since vectors are guaranteed to be stored in contiguous memory), e.g.

```
cout << "12345 in Hex is " << &hexConversion[0] << endl;
```

Comment: or use std::vector::data in C++11 (which will avoid any issues if vec is empty)