# Print a wchar_t emoji on console with wcout in C++ strange behavior

Tags: c++, unicode, cout, emoji, wchar

I am trying to print an emoji on standard output console in C++ on Mac OS X environment – clang.

This first code works correctly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cwchar>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]){
  char myEmoji[4] = "⛩";
  std::cout << "emoji example: " << myEmoji << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

and on console I can see:

```
./emoji ; exit
emoji example: ⛩
logout
```

When I try this, it works unexpectedly for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cwchar>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]){
  wchar_t myEmoji = L'⛩';
  std::wcout << "emoji example: " << myEmoji << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

and this time I get:

```
./emoji ; exit
emoji example: logout
```

Where I am wrong?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't stick non-ASCII characters in a source file to begin with.  Use escape sequences.

Comment: Your is a good advice – surely – but nothing of illicit: for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493785/how-i-can-print-the-wchar-t-values-to-console) and in many other ones.

Comment: Can you rig up a version that works, using, say, `std::wstring` inline aggregate-initialized with the emoji? Doing that will likely tell you where the problem is in your program – which is either a) the storage, assignment and management of wide-character data, or b) an issue with the `std::wout` instance of`std::wostream` (which of all of the STL internals, the stream I/O freaks me out the most and I have no idea how it works; there are many subtle options hidden in layers of classes and subclasses therein).