# Trying to find exec file using GetModuleFileName but returns numbers

Tags: c++, getmodulefilename

Here is my code. I have a buffer to save the output but it returns numbers. could someone explain this and how would I be able to get my exe file?

```
wchar_t buffer[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileName(NULL,buffer,sizeof(buffer));
cout << buffer << "\n";
```

Comment: Fix: `wcout << buffer << L"\n"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How I can print the wchar\_t values to console?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493785/how-i-can-print-the-wchar-t-values-to-console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cout is ansi version of console output. You have to use wide version of cout: wcout:

```
wchar_t buffer[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileName(NULL,buffer,sizeof(buffer));
wcout << buffer << "\n";
```

Or use the ansi version of everything:

```
char buffer[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileNameA(NULL,buffer,sizeof(buffer));
cout << buffer << "\n";
```