# Why does wprintf transliterate Russian text in Unicode into Latin on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, printf, non-ascii-characters, wchar

Why does the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main() {
  wprintf(L"Привет, мир!");
}
```

print "Privet, mir!" on Linux? Specifically, why does it transliterate Russian text in Unicode into Latin as opposed to transcoding it into UTF-8 or using replacement characters?

Demonstration of this behavior on Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/36zEcG

The non-wide version `printf("Привет, мир!")` prints this text as expected ("Привет, мир!").

Comment: Out of curiosity, why even use `wchar` on Linux?

Comment: There is no reason to use `wchar_t` since it's non-portable. I just came across this "interesting" behavior when answering another SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65480111/471164,

Comment: In my system, it just prints `??????, ???!`. Could you check `/usr/share/i18n/locales/C` and see if there are any rules starting with `translit` in there?

Comment: @Heinzi, you can check locales on godbolt if interested - there is a link in the question.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Because conversion of wide characters is done according to the currently set locale. By default a C program always starts with a "C" locale which only supports ASCII characters.

You have to switch to any Russian or UTF-8 locale first:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.utf8"); // Russian Unicode
setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8"); // English US Unicode
```

Or to a current system locale (which is likely what you need):

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

The full program will be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main() {
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.utf8");
  wprintf(L"Привет, мир!\n");
}
```

As for your code working as-is on other machines - this is due to how libc operates there. Some implementations (like musl) do not support non-Unicode locales and thus can unconditionally translate wide characters to an UTF-8 sequence.

Comment: It prints prints verbatim `Privet, mir!` when I run it on godbolt with or without `setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.utf8")` or `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")`.

Comment: But why transliteration? Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Do you have "ru_RU.utf8" locale installed on your computer? If not, then setting it will fail. Use `""` (default locale) which is likely an UTF-8 one. Any unicode locale will do.

Comment: @vitaut I am not sure tbh, but I think it is just illegal to output those characters without locale and libc probably can do whatever it wants. Transliteration is a nice way to produce valid and still readable output.

Comment: @Jabberwocky what locale are you using then? Try "en_US.utf8" if you are in US.

Comment: After generating `ru_RU.UTF-8` locale, the program works for me. Note that the _first call_ to any `stdout` functions has to be done _after_ `setlocale`.

Comment: @KamilCuk it should work with default locale too (if it is set to a unicode locale) - it is important to have this program generate expected output on any machine with unicode support and not tie it to a specific language.

Comment: One thing to make sure is that you have a utf compatible locale installed using `locale -a` in a terminal. Then select one from the list that command provides.

Answer (score 10):

> why does it transliterate Russian text in Unicode into Latin as opposed to transcoding it into UTF-8 or using replacement characters?

Because the starting locale of your program is the default one, the `C` locale. So it's translating wide string into `C` locale. `C` locale doesn't handle UTF-8 nor any unicode, so your standard library does it's best to translate wide characters into some basic character set used in `C` locale.

You may change the locale to *any* UTF-8 locale and the program should output UTF-8 string.

Note: (in implementation I know of) the encoding of the `FILE` stream is determined and *saved at the time* the stream orientation (wide vs normal) is chosen. Remember to set the locale *before* doing anything with `stdout` (ie. [this](https://godbolt.org/z/365vMG) vs [this](https://godbolt.org/z/aEeh8e)).