# How can I wprintf a value of a character in C++

Tags: c++, string, integer, char, printf

**How can I print the Ascii value of one char (wstring) ?**

For example I want to get the Ascii Value of Ö which is 214.

I tried this:

```
std::wstring ws2 = L"Ö";        
wprintf(L"This is wpritf for int: %ls(%i)...\n", ws2.c_str(), ws2.c_str());
```

but it gives me:

This is wpritf for int: ╓(5238748)...

Comment: Strongly related, if not a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493785/how-i-can-print-the-wchar-t-values-to-console

Comment: `%i` is for integers but `ws2->c_str()` is not an integer. `std::wcout << static_cast<int>(ws2[0]);`

Comment: Ö doesn't have a value in standard ASCII (which only covers values up to 127).

Comment: [ASCII](https://eljay.neocities.org/ASCII) goes from 0x00 to 0x7F.  `Ö` isn't part of ASCII.

Comment: *"I want to get the Ascii Value of Ö which is 214."* -- More precisely (since ASCII stops at 127), you want to get the **integer** code for Ö. Which already goes a long way towards explaining what you need to do.

Comment: `wprintf(L"This is wpritf for int: %lc(%i)...\n", ws2[0], ws2[0]);`

Comment: Hmm... what if you stuck to ASCII, but had a longer string? How would you print the integer code for `Q` given `std::string str = "Quick";`? Can we use that as a starting point?

Comment: Why use "C"'s unsafe printf function? What's wrong with using (C++20's) [std::wformat](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format)?

Comment: @PepijnKramer: Unless there are unstated formatting requirements, we don't particularly need `format`/`wformat` either. Once we've retrieved the correct value, `std::cout << value;` meets the requirements given.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_WTEXT);` at the top:

```cpp
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string>

int main(void) {
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_WTEXT);

    std::wstring ws2= L"Ö";

    wprintf(L"This is wpritf for int: %ls(%i)...\n", ws2.c_str(), static_cast<int>(ws2[0]));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you have a wstring longer than one character, you must output as through an array using a loop.

Comment: I think your text misses the most significant changes you made. If you drop `_setmode` you still get `214` in the output, don't you? (Outputting the string is tangential to what was asked.)

Comment: I don't know the main goal of the author of the question and considering that Ö has no value in ASCII [ASCII Table`](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html), I decided that maybe my attempt will lead him to the solution he needs.

Comment: *"I don't know the main goal of the author of the question"* -- It's right there in the question: *"I want to get [X] which is 214."* The author wants to get 214, regardless of the misuse of terminology.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to print out the value of the first character of a string, as an integer.

So, you retrieve the first character of the string like `ws2[0]`, and the print it out as an integer (using the `%d` or `%i` conversion).

```c
wprintf("%d\n", ws2[0]);
```

This does have a problem that's somewhat difficult to really correct well though: since `ws2` is a `std::wstring`, `ws2[0]` is a `wchar_t`. But `printf` doesn't provide a conversion to print out the integer value of a `wchar_t`. So we're kind of depending on a `wchar_t` either being an `int`, or being some smaller type (e.g., `short`) that will be promoted to `int` when it's passed to a variadic function (like `printf` and company). Otherwise, the value we passed has a different type from the value we told `printf` to expect with the `%d` conversion, so we get undefined behavior.

Personally, I *generally* prefer iostreams over `printf`. They determine how to format a item based on its type, so what we'd probably want to do with them is explicitly convert `ws2[0]` to an integer type to print it out.

```cpp
std::cout << static_cast<unsigned>(ws2[0]) << "\n";
```

Note that even though the value we're working with is a `wchar_t`, we're printing out its numeric value, so there's no particular need to write it to a wide-character stream like `wcout` instead of `cout` (though `wcout` would also work fine).